# Crawling fails with 404 error message, but the IIS log tell a different story

Tags: crawling

In our clean SP2010 install, crawling stops immediately, just logging a single error message:

```
The object was not found. ( Error from SharePoint site: HttpStatusCode NotFound The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found. )
```

Looking at the IIS log does, surprisingly, not  confirm this. Here are all the log entries related to crawling:

```
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2010-09-01 15:20:42 127.0.0.1 GET / - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+4.01;+Windows+NT;+MS+Search+6.0+Robot) 401 1 2148074254 15
2010-09-01 15:20:42 127.0.0.1 GET / - 80 0#.w|global\cre-nhk 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+4.01;+Windows+NT;+MS+Search+6.0+Robot) 200 0 0 46
2010-09-01 15:20:42 127.0.0.1 GET /Pages/Forside.aspx - 80 0#.w|global\cre-nhk 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+4.01;+Windows+NT;+MS+Search+6.0+Robot) 200 0 995 937
2010-09-01 15:20:43 127.0.0.1 GET /_vti_bin/sitedata.asmx - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+4.01;+Windows+NT;+MS+Search+6.0+Robot) 401 1 2148074254 0
2010-09-01 15:20:43 127.0.0.1 GET /_vti_bin/sitedata.asmx - 80 0#.w|global\cre-nhk 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+4.01;+Windows+NT;+MS+Search+6.0+Robot) 200 0 0 15
```

As you can see, just a fairly normal handshaking of 401’s and 200’s.

Finally, here are the ULS log entries:

```
09-01-2010 17:36:15.36  mssdmn.exe (0x0E9C)     0x1E24  SharePoint Server Search        Indexing        fsa0    Monitorable     GetVirtualServerPolicy fail. error 2147750401, strStsUrl http://demo.dsr.dk     
09-01-2010 17:36:15.36  mssdmn.exe (0x0E9C)     0x1E24  SharePoint Server Search        PHSts   dvt6    High    SetSTSErrorInfo ErrorMessage = Error from SharePoint site: HttpStatusCode NotFound The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found. hr = 80041201  [sts3util.cxx:5095]  d:\office\source\search\native\gather\protocols\sts3\sts3util.cxx   
09-01-2010 17:36:15.36  mssdmn.exe (0x0E9C)     0x1E24  SharePoint Server Search        PHSts   dvi3    High    ***** Couldn't retrieve server http://demo.dsr.dk policy, hr = 80041201         [sts3util.cxx:1738]  d:\office\source\search\native\gather\protocols\sts3\sts3util.cxx  
09-01-2010 17:36:15.36  mssdmn.exe (0x0E9C)     0x1E24  SharePoint Server Search        PHSts   dvu0    High    STS3::StoreCachedError: Object initialization failed.  Message:  "Error from SharePoint site: HttpStatusCode NotFound The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found." HR: 80041201  [sts3util.cxx:5189]  d:\office\source\search\native\gather\protocols\sts3\sts3util.cxx
09-01-2010 17:36:15.36  mssdmn.exe (0x0E9C)     0x1E24  SharePoint Server Search        PHSts   dvg4    High    ****** Server demo.dsr.dk security initialization failed, hr = 80041201 error Message Error from SharePoint site: HttpStatusCode NotFound The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.  [sts3util.cxx:1358]  d:\office\source\search\native\gather\protocols\sts3\sts3util.cxx  
09-01-2010 17:36:15.36  mssdmn.exe (0x0E9C)     0x1E24  SharePoint Server Search        PHSts   dv5x    High    CSTS3Accessor::InitServer: Initialize STS Helper failed. Return error to caller, hr=80041201  [sts3acc.cxx:1691]  d:\office\source\search\native\gather\protocols\sts3\sts3acc.cxx     
09-01-2010 17:36:15.36  mssdmn.exe (0x0E9C)     0x1E24  SharePoint Server Search        PHSts   dv3t    High    CSTS3Accessor::InitURLType fails, Url http://demo.dsr.dk, hr=80041201           [sts3acc.cxx:258]  d:\office\source\search\native\gather\protocols\sts3\sts3acc.cxx     
09-01-2010 17:36:15.36  mssdmn.exe (0x0E9C)     0x1E24  SharePoint Server Search        PHSts   dvb1    High    CSTS3Accessor::Init fails, Url http://demo.dsr.dk, hr=80041201                  [sts3handler.cxx:312]  d:\office\source\search\native\gather\protocols\sts3\sts3handler.cxx     
09-01-2010 17:36:15.36  mssdmn.exe (0x0E9C)     0x1E24  SharePoint Server Search        PHSts   dvb2    High    CSTS3Handler::CreateAccessorExD: Return error to caller, hr=80041201            [sts3handler.cxx:330]  d:\office\source\search\native\gather\protocols\sts3\sts3handler.cxx    
09-01-2010 17:36:15.36  mssdmn.exe (0x0E9C)     0x1E24  SharePoint Server Search        FilterDaemon    e4ye    High    FLTRDMN: Errorinfo is "Error from SharePoint site: HttpStatusCode NotFound The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found."  [fltrsink.cxx:553]  d:\office\source\search\native\mssdmn\fltrsink.cxx
09-01-2010 17:36:15.38  mssearch.exe (0x1BD0)   0x0F28  SharePoint Server Search        GatherPI        e5e0    High    advising status change NSC_FLUSH (467f7b97-cba6-4ebd-ab96-4fa7af378718-crawl-0 Portal_Content crawl -1)  [gatherobj.cxx:4512]  d:\office\source\search\native\gather\server\gatherobj.cxx      
09-01-2010 17:36:15.38  mssearch.exe (0x1BD0)   0x0F28  SharePoint Server Search        Gatherer        cd11    Warning The start address http://demo.dsr.dk cannot be crawled.  Context: Application
```

Things checked and verified:
·         DisableLoopbackCheck is disabled
·         The crawler user (cre-nhk) has “Full Control” on the web application (that should include “read all”)
·         The crawler user can log on to the site and view all pages when accessing them using Internet Explorer
·         There is no Alternate Access Mapping used

I see that someone else has a similar issue:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010setup/thread/f3c61b53-304a-4c2a-a370-d0e573219d1d

But in our case:
 - it's a clean install, no upgrading
 - Plain HTTP, no certificates

Any answer/input most appreciated!

Best regards

Thomas

Answer (score 2):

We resolved this issue by going back to crawling using the farm admin account. This project has a custom approach to authentication, using a custom MembershipProvider, which seems to bite us again and again. So, as a general advice, avoiding authenticating that way if you can. (And had the project started anew, they probably would have chosen a somewhat different approach…)

Regards

Thomas

Comment: Hi Thomas, we have exactly same issue today and workaround it by using Farm admin as crawling account. We don't have custom authentication solution and the original crawler account on the same domain as farm admin. What could be wrong? Do you fixed your authentication issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure, that the crawl account can access the pages.
Even though it usually has full read access, it cannot read pages, that were never approved / published, so login as the search account and make sure, it can at least read the homepage of the root sitecollection ("/").

Two additional standard checks in these cases are:

- [disable loopback check](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepoint_foxhole/archive/2010/06/21/disableloopbackcheck-lets-do-it-the-right-way.aspx)
- Enter host headers in hosts file with ip 127.0.0.1 (not with another local IP)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Windows Authentication is enabled on the site you are trying to index.